# Module to make BODY code come from a file in Drupal?

Tags: drupal

Is there a module or a way to make it so that the data that usually goes in the body when creating a node, comes from an html/php file. Ideally, a dropdown below the body where you can select the file would be the best.

1. Anybody know how to do it?
2. Do you think this is wise?

Answer (score 0):

No it's not wise, you should never execute php from user input no matter how trusted they are. I'm not just a security wank, we've honestly had clients bring down their servers because of this.

Give us some more info about your goal though and I'm sure we can figure something out.

Comment: I think you misunderstood. I want a folder, e.g. files/html/*.html

Comment: And then those files must be selectable within a node. And that must be the output of that node.